# My doctrine is Really Slow. Simple query and one second to get the result

Tags: php, mysql, performance, doctrine-1.2

Here is my setup:
Windows Server 2008 R2
MySql 5.1.562
Php 5.3.2
Doctrine 1.2

Anybody have an Idea why my query is taking about one second to perform a simple query.

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()) ."::::::" . microtime(true)."<br />";

             $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->from("Ordering")
            ->where("client_id = ?",array($_SESSION["UserID"]));

            $ResProduct = $q->execute();

echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()) ."::::::" . microtime(true)."<br />";
```

Here is the result of the 2 echo to show you how long it's take to perform the query.

```
2011-04-21 01:48:24::::::1303364904.8051
2011-04-21 01:48:25::::::1303364905.8418
```

An other thing, there is no data in the database.

**Edit**
I Perform the query directly in the mysql console and get the result very quickly

```
mysql> select * from Ordering where client_id = 2;
+----+------------+-------+------+-----------+
| id | product_id | price | qty  | client_id |
+----+------------+-------+------+-----------+
|  7 |          1 |  0.89 |   20 |         2 |
+----+------------+-------+------+-----------+
1 row in set  (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Love the title *"My doctrine is really slow"*... ;-D

Comment: I don't see why you use `microtime_float()` on php 5.3.2. Use `microtime(true)`.

Comment: Thx, I didn't know that for microtime(true). Nice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `microtime(true)` instead of `microtime_float()`
- Configure MySQL not to resolve IP's of connecting clients: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-name-resolve
- `client_id = ?`- why do you cast `$_SESSION["UserID"]` to array? I think this is unnecessary.

Comment: The guys here is a Master :) Thanks a lot @FractalizeR. You save my Night. Many Thanks. 39 MS executing the Same query but with skip-name-resolve
skip-host-cache in the my.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code doesn't seem *wrong* or anything.

Basically, though, your SQL query will typically look like this :

```
select *
from Ordering
where client_id = 123456
```

Which means that **setting an index on the `client_id` column** should probably help -- a lot, if there are many rows in that table.

A couple of relevant links, about that :

- [`CREATE INDEX` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html)
- [How MySQL Uses Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Comment: I already have index on client_id. And as I said in my post, there are no data in the database yet.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity have you attempted a RawSQL Query?  We had an issue similar to this and it ended up being a DNS issue.  Even though everything was supposed to be localhost the apache server was going external to resolve the address to mysql for some reason.