# Doctrine 2 configuration and performance

Tags: php, performance, configuration, doctrine-orm, wamp

I've got some problems with Doctrine 2 on my localhost. One page, which uses only one query, is loading on localhost in about 1.5s. Meanwhile, on remote server loading takes about 300ms (http://gieromaniak.pl/contact). I have no idea what could be wrong. Is it Doctrine 2 configuration or sth else? Or maybe I don't have some PHP extension on my server (WAMP - Apache 2.4.2, PHP 5.4.3)?

Nevertheless, I'm including source code of my Doctrine configuration file:

```
<?php
use Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader,
    Doctrine\ORM\Configuration,
    Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager,
    Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type,
    Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache,
    Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\EchoSqlLogger;


// include the class loader directly
require_once __DIR__ . '/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php';

$doctrineClassLoader = new ClassLoader('Doctrine', __DIR__ . '/');
$doctrineClassLoader->register();

Config::load('base');
Config::load('database');

if(Config::get('base.mode') == 'development') {
    $bProxyGen = TRUE;
} else {
    $bProxyGen = FALSE;
}

// Set up caches
$cache = new ArrayCache;
$config = new Configuration;
$config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);
$config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);

// Metadata Driver
$driverImpl = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver($models);
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);

// Proxy configuration
$config->setProxyDir(PATH_ROOT.Config::get('database.proxy_dir'));
$config->setProxyNamespace(Config::get('database.proxy_namespace'));
$config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses($bProxyGen);

// Database connection information
$connectionOptions = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'charset' => 'utf8',

    'dbname' => 'dbname',
    'user' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password',
);

// Create EntityManager
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($connectionOptions, $config);
```

Thank You in advance for any help!

Comment: what is your server configuration on the remote server?

Comment: @bleuscyther PHP 5.3.21, Linux, Apache 2. Need sth else?

Comment: I use to have Wamp as a Local machine test. I switched to Xampp but i can confirm that the process is slower on Wamp/Xampp/Windows than on Linux. ALso you should use proxies and cache if you want to improve the performance. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/improving-performance.html

Comment: Do you have an opcode cache locally? Because that makes a huge difference. Also consider using a metadata cache, especially if your configuration is annotation-driven.

Comment: @bleuscyther As You should see, I'm using ArrayCache and Proxy. But, do not know why, Proxy classes ("__CG__" etc.) aren't generating in desired directory (on remote server it's all right).

Comment: @Ocramius First, tell me what's "opcode cache", and then I will tell You if I have this :D?

Comment: yes :), sorry, i overlooked the code . On windows you can clear the temporary folder. You are using array cache on dev ( so it's  ok ). Opcode cache like APC or Memcached are recommanded on production

Comment: @bleuscyther So I know. But still... localhost is dev and I need to run it faster :).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740114/my-doctrine-is-really-slow-simple-query-and-one-second-to-get-the-result

Comment: I don't think it's Doctrine , i think its web dev on windows home edition that sucks :). You can increase mysql perf. And also increase the memory limit allocated to php on tour php.ini file put it to 512M

Comment: @bleuscyther Well... increased memory limit didn't helped. I've also added `skip-name-resolve` line to my "my.ini" file... and it's still the same... :(

Comment: @bleuscyther I've also other projects on my WAMP server. They're not based on Doctrine (it's Kohana Framework) and they work fine. So... maybe mysql perf is ok?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommand to install apc and to improve mysql performance:

### Install APC

I strongly recommend to use Wamp server (x86) for that, the apc.dll for the x64 version of windows doesn't work well.

follow [this](http://docs.moodle.org/24/en/Installing_APC_in_Windows) tutorial with the following modifications:

- the [link to apc.dll](http://dev.freshsite.pl/php-accelerators/apc.html)
- find the **Zend Extension Build** or **PHP Extension Build** ,from your phpinfo(); you can use that `http://localhost/?phpinfo=1` for your WAMP localhost
- the **Zend Extension Build** should be like this :

> API220100525,TS,VC9

- Note the TS word, it can be blank; look if their is a different word like NTS
- download the latest version according to the TS or NTS value
- rename the dll php_apc.dll
- put the php_apc.dll in `YourWampFolder/bin/php/ext/`
- there are 2 php.ini files in wamp : `wamp\bin\apache\apacheX.X.XX\bin\` and `wamp\bin\php\phpX.X.X\` (replace the X.X... by your versions)
  write `extension=php_apc.dll;` in both of them
- close/open Wamp (not restart)
- from the wamp icon->php->PHP extensions->php_apc.dll check to activate
- restart wamp

you can verify that APC is running by downloading the apc.php file into your project dirctory. You will find it in the compressed [file available at the PECL website](http://pecl.php.net/package/APC). Take the latest version.

Now from your browser : `http://localhost/yourproject/apc.php`

You can modify the settings of APC from php.ini (try both)

exemple :

```
//php.ini
...

[APC]
apc.ttl=7200
apc.user_ttl=7200
apc.shm_segments=3
apc.shm_size=90M
apc.max_file_size = 2M
apc.include_once_override = 1
```

just in case you want to clear the cache

```
// resetcache.php
<?php
if ( $_GET['pass'] == 'yes') {
if(function_exists('apc_clear_cache')){
        if (apc_clear_cache() && apc_clear_cache('user'))
                print 'All Clear!';
        else
                print 'Clearing Failed!';

        print '<pre>';
        print_r(apc_cache_info());
        print '</pre>';
}else print "fuction_doesn't exist";
        } else {
        print 'Authenticate, please!';
}
```

i put some extra security to prevent unwanted access but do not include `apc.php` and `clearcache.php` in the production server.

### Increase Mysql performance

1. [link1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18614/wamp-server-performance-tuning-for-mysql)
2. [link2](http://forums.kayako.com/threads/mysql-performance-improvement-tips.25331/)
3. [link3](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/29/what-to-tune-in-mysql-server-after-installation/)

### Clean local machine

You can clean your browser cache and temp folders. [CCleaner](http://www.filehippo.com/download_ccleaner/)

This is all that i did to increase the speed of Doctrine2 on my local machine in the past.
you can also monitor the Ram used by Mysql/Apache process to see if you don' t need to buy/allocate more RAM.

Comment: :( change apc.shm_segments=1, try other settings to see if that helps,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583253/what-could-cause-local-apc-to-be-slower-than-remote-memcached and